# QMainWindow windows always on top not working sometimes

Tags: windows, qt, user-interface

On windows 7 I have problem with window flag. I added this line in the constructor

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint );
```

when windows is going to render (after ctrl + r in qt creator) if suddenly i click on somewhere on text editor(qt creator text editor or in notepad if is open) this flag is not working correctly and rendered window stays on background. I found windows this solution:

```
if(GetForegroundWindow() != reinterpret_cast<HWND>(winId())){
   qDebug() << "Here is my problem";
}
```

but now If I set again it doesn't working and window anyway stays background.

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint );
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is your window a frameless window?

Comment: Yes it was. I removed FramelessWindowHint flag and it works. I hope this was reason. thanks ))

Comment: This is most likely a usability nightmare. Why is your application so important that it needs to steal *my* desktop from me (the user)? Aren't native mechanisms like notifications enough to do your job? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to do web browser which will render web application. user can't  do another operations(browse internet or local file systems) while my this is open